# Jech Third Edition Set Theory p191 Theorem 13.21 Jensen. What is the Essence of the Diamond Principle?

Tags: set-theory, infinitary-combinatorics

The diamond principle in theorem 13.21 of Jech : There exists Z =  $\langle S_\alpha : \alpha < \omega_1\rangle$  with $S_\alpha\subset \alpha$, such that for every X $\subset \omega_1$, the set Y=$\{\alpha < \omega_1 : X  \cap \alpha = S_\alpha\}$ is a stationary subset of $\omega_1$.

If X is a single ordinal $\beta$ (which could be the empty set $\phi$ ) , then Y would have a maximum $\alpha$ with $\beta \cap\alpha$ = $S_\alpha$ if the $S_\alpha$ are "increasing in size as $\alpha$ increases", which would mean Y isn't stationary.  However if Z includes a cofinal sequence of "special" $S_\alpha$ all of which are = $\beta$ (i.e. $\langle$$\alpha$ : $S_\alpha$=$\beta$$\rangle$ is cofinal in $\omega_1$)    then this would allow Y to become big enough to have a chance of being stationary, as the diamond principle applies to all subsets X of $\omega_1$ ?

Is this the essence of the diamond principle - is it all about how cofinal sequences of identical sets (for a given X) can be interleaved together to allow a large stationary set to be made, by requiring that it applies to all $X\subset \omega_1$? With this interpretation it looks quite hard to do in general without limiting what the X can be - as there are so many X in general (though in the constructible universe the number of X is limited so the intuition would be that it "looks" achievable there, which is the case by Theorem 13.21).

Comment: No, this is not the beauty of diamond sequences. Sure, it applies to bounded subsets of $\omega_{1}$. What's better though that it applies to unbounded subsets of $\omega_{1}$ as well. This allows for recursive constructions with 'combinatorial coherence' properties. See for example the construction of a Suslin tree from $\Diamond$.

Comment: Morever, being stationary is much stronger than merely being unbounded and it's crucial in the application of $\Diamond$ sequences that we capture a given subset on a stationary set, not just on an unbounded one.

Comment: The point is that it gives you a local *reflection principle* (people usually call diamond a guessing principle for this reason). I think of it as the *correct* set-theoretic version of $\mathsf{CH}$ (and recall that Shelah has proved that $2^\kappa=\kappa^+$ is equivalent to $\diamondsuit_{\kappa^+}$ for all uncountable $\kappa$).

Comment: Thanks - much deeper than it looked to me ! Is there an intuitive explanation why its equivalent to CH (I will of course follow up both these points - much appreciated) ?

Comment: It is not equivalent to $\mathsf{CH}$. $\kappa=\omega$ is the only cardinal where the equivalence fails.

Comment: OK.Thanks - I will close the question by answering it with "Please see comments".

Comment: @andres E. Caicedo OK thanks. Also I note that if X is unbounded then for Y to be unbounded requires that there is a cofinal sequence of S alpha that are increasing initial segments of X. If X is bounded then there is a cofinal sequence of S alpha that are = X. So Z contains S alpha that increasingly approximate (but in general never equal, if unbounded) X. This applies for any X. So the link with CH is now very clear, though I don't know what stationarity brings - is it actually needed for the CH link ?

Comment: Stationarity is essentially for free if there is any correct guessing at all. More precisely, if a sequence $(\mathcal{S}_\alpha\mid \alpha<\omega_1)$ is such that for all $\alpha$, $\mathcal{S}_\alpha$ is a countable collection of subsets of $\alpha$, and for all $X\subseteq\omega_1$ there is an *infinite* $\alpha$ such that $X\cap \alpha\in\mathcal{S}_\alpha$, then $\diamondsuit$ holds. But many reflection principles have this behavior, that ensuring reflection at some point actually implies that we can ask for reflection at many points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see all of the comments, thanks.

Note that for unbounded X, X $\cap \alpha$ = $S_\alpha$ picks out those $S_\alpha$ that are initial segments of X, so if X is unbounded there will be an unbounded sequence of $S_\alpha$ that increasingly approximate X via its initial segments. So as the diamond principle applies to all X which are subsets of $\omega_1$, the sequence Z will contain limiting approximations to all subsets of $\omega_1$.